# How to do custom filter option in bootstrap datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have api results in bootstrap datatables. I will have 3 select dropdown box for filter the results. which will have combined filter search results. how to show using bootstrap datatables.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    } );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3L0jr4of/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are looking for something like this
https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

When i had to use multiple filters on columns , this worked out for me..

Happy coding :)

Comment: Superb Thanks surya. I am looking for this one only. Got the solution. Have to try this in my application